# shell script not storing command output as variable

Tags: linux, python-2.7, shell, zsh, prompt

I have defined a function to check if the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set, and if so, figure out the current python version.

```
theme_python_prompt () {
    if [ -v VIRTUAL_ENV ]
    then
        local VERSION="$(python -V)"
        echo -n "%{$fg[yellow]%}%{$reset_color%}:${VERSION}(%{$fg[magenta]%}$(basename ${VIRTUAL_ENV})%{$reset_color%})"
    fi
}
```

But, this is just outputting the result of `python -V` to stdout instead of storing it into the variable. Printing the whole stack (`set -x`) shows the following:

```
+theme_python_prompt:1> [ -v VIRTUAL_ENV ']'                                   
+theme_python_prompt:3> python -V                    
Python 2.7.15                          
+theme_python_prompt:3> echo ''         
+theme_python_prompt:3> local VERSION=''
+theme_python_prompt:4> basename /home/hjpotter92/.virtualenvs/test-2fI9Fep8
+theme_python_prompt:4> echo -n $'%{\C-[[33m%}%{\C-[[00m%}:(%{\C-[[35m%}test-2fI9Fep8%{\C-[[00m%})'
```

A similar function to fetch me `rbenv` info is working without issues:

```
theme_rbenv_prompt () {
    if ! type rbenv > /dev/null
    then
        echo -n ""
    else
        local VERSION="$(rbenv_prompt_info)"
        [ "$VERSION" != "system" ] && echo "%{$fg_bold[red]%}%{$reset_color%}:${VERSION} " || echo -n ""
    fi
}
```

where `rbenv_prompt_info` is from [oh-my-zsh plugin](https://git.io/rbenv_prompt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python -V` prints to `stderr`, not `stdout`. You need to redirect the standard error to standard output, otherwise you'll get an empty string.

Use `local VERSION=$(python -V 2>&1)` instead.

Comment: Wow! This is not the case with python 3.6.5 (the one I tested with). However, older python versions do output to stderr... :/